# Clonar seu próprio projeto do GitHub em uma máquina diferente

Tags: git, github

Estou iniciando os estudo com Git e GitHub e tenho uma dúvida que não consegui encontrar na documentação ou em fóruns.

1. Eu tenho 2 computadores, o pessoal e o de trabalho.
2. Iniciei um projeto no GitHub  com a máquina pessoal usando GitBash.
3. Na máquina de trabalho eu baixei o projeto que criei no GitHub usando a outra máquina.
4. Fiz algumas alterações no projeto e quero atualizar no GitHub .

Resumindo: Eu quero baixar meu próprio projeto do GitHub em outra máquina e salvar a atualização realizada.

Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Você tem que clonar o mesmo repositório nas duas máquinas

```
git clone https://github.com/(...).git
```

E caso esteja trabalhando na sua máquina do trabalho e tenha feito algumas alterações que gostaria de obter na sua outra máquina, basta enviá-las ao *remote*, através do `git push`.

Quando você executa `git push` você envia seus commits para o *remote*, ou seja GitHub no seu caso.

> Repositórios remotos são versões de seu repositório hospedado na Internet ou em >uma rede qualquer. Você pode ter vários deles, cada um dos quais geralmente é ou >somente leitura ou leitura/escrita. Colaborar com outras pessoas envolve o >gerenciamento destes repositórios remotos, fazer pushing(atualizar) e >pulling(obter) de dados para e deles quando você precisar compartilhar seu >trabalho.

[referencia](https://www.git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Fundamentos-de-Git-Trabalhando-de-Forma-Remota)

Answer (score 0):

Oi, Valdir! Tudo bem?

Se entendi bem queres trabalhar com teu projeto em duas máquinas.
Isso não deveria ser um problema. Basicamente seria mais ou menos isso:

Verifica se tu está com o `git config` certinho:

usuário: `git config user.name "Seu Nome";`

email: `git config user.email seuemail@dominio.com`

Se estiver e não resolver tenta o seguinte:

```
//Converter um diretório existente em repositório do github:
cd ~/[caminho de onde está teu projeto no pc]
git init
git add .
git commit -m "V1"
git remote add origin ~/[caminho de onde está teu projeto no pc]
git push origin master
```

Daí tu deve salvar as alterações...

```
git add .
git commit -m "Versao modificada"
git push origin master
```

Na máquina do trabalho tu precisa clonar o repositório. Digamos que esteja tudo em uma pasta chamada "Projetos":

```
cd ~/Projetos
git clone -o [nome do teu projeto] ~/[caminho de onde está teu projeto nesse pc]
cd [nome do teu projeto]
git remote add origin ~/[caminho de onde está teu projeto nesse pc]
```

Daí tu atualiza o diretório de trabalho a partir do repositório central:

```
cd ~/[caminho de onde está teu projeto nesse pc]
git pull origin master
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Abraço!

Answer (score -3):

Ja faz tem a pergunta mais pra quem estiver procurando, esta aqui uma resposta que pode resolver, no meu caso o problema foi a versão do git instalada, desinstalei e baixei a versão antiga, OBS: baixe uma versão antiga do git como a Git 64 bit 2.38.1

No meu fiz isso e funcionou, quando você clona o repositório a pasta oculta do git vem junto, assim sendo ele já tem tudo configurado, branch master, origin já está tudo lá.

Em um pc novo apenas configure o git globalmente e na hora de fazer o push, o github vai pedir para se conectar ao git e ai é só você logar normal e pronto.